# Why does GetType() give me the derived type but GetType().GetProperties() gives me the base class properties?

Tags: c#, system.reflection, gettype, getproperties

I'm trying to avoid code duplication by having a function in a base class that creates a list of properties which implement a specific interface.

When I call the function it doesn't work as I hope.

While trying to debug, I found the following results which I don't understand:

Call `GetType()` gives me the derived type. (Which is what I want.)

However, `GetType().GetProperties()` only gives me the base class properties and not the properties in the type returned by `GetType()`.

```
interface IParameter
{
    string ParameterValue { get; }
}

class SearchBase
{
    public string SearchName { get; set; }

    protected List<IParameter> ListOfParameters()
    {
        // this gives me the derived type object of SearchOne
        var type = GetType();

        // this only gives me the base class properties of SearchBase
        var typeProperteis = type.GetProperties();

        // I want this to return a list of all the IParameter properties in the derived classes 
        return GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => typeof(IParameter).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)).Select(x => (IParameter)x.GetValue(this)).ToList();
    }
}

class SearchOne : SearchBase
{
    public IParameter Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public IParameter Parameter2 { get; set; }
    public IParameter Parameter3 { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var properties = ListOfParameters();
    }
}
```

It seems counter intuitive to me that it will give me the derived type from the base type but not the properties of the derived type. (I could understand if it only gave me the base class in both examples, but I'm confused why it's a bit of each.)

**Edit:**

It turns out the property in my derived type wasn't marked `public`. Once I made it public it was returned in the list.

Comment: Running `ListOfParameters` generated an exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'IParameter'"

Comment: But `GetProperties` returns me the parameters (and then there is @shingo 's exception).

Comment: I've fixed the exception in the code I included, which is a trivial example and not a copy. Also, embarrassingly, it turns out while refactoring the only property in one of the classes into the base class, I had marked it protected rather than public.

Comment: You can always give it `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the docs: [Type.GetProperties() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-8.0) says:

> It returns all **public** instance and static properties, both those
> defined by the type represented by the current Type object **as well as
> those inherited from its base types**.

Comment: Can you please clarify how that answers OP's claim "However, GetType().GetProperties() only gives me the base class properties"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov While I completely agree with your comment and it was the first thing I thought after reading the answer, it turns out it does provide the answer to what my actual problem was. Embarrassingly, it turns out while refactoring the only property in one of the classes into the base class, I had made it protected rather than public. I was in a hurry and well past needing a break... 

So, the response would have been better if it included the suggestion, **double check your properties are all public**.